# Ninject MVC together with WCF extension does not work with InRequestScope

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, ninject

I have gotten Ninject MVC to work with Ninject WCF to get it to work I added two lines to CreateKernel method

```
kernel.Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();
KernelContainer.Kernel = kernel;
```

The dependencies are injected, but the Dispose method is not called, I've tried both with InRequestScope and doing my own scope Func return OperationContext.Current as Scope object, but the dispose is not called.

**Update 2012-09-05**
This info is obsolete, for MVC and WCF download from Nuget Ninject.MV3 and Ninject.Extensions.WCF (3.x) the MVC Nuget template will add a Ninject bootstrapper NinjectWebCommon.cs and to add support in a svc for ninject eddit the svc xml (Right click / View markup) and add *Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"* to the xml node

Comment: I'm up-voting this question because it shows how to use NInject for MVC and WCF at the same time, which is really hard to find a good example for.

Comment: This info is obsolete, see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reply to Remo's answer because I'm a stackoverflow n00b but the issue with the 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' exception is that it has moved from System.Core in .net 4.0 to mscorlib in .net 4.5. If you install .net 4.5 the problem disappears. I think something was built with .net 4.5 in the mix. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/3 Sounds like it will be fixed soon.
As for the Wcf InRequestScope issue Remo gave me some help today on the google groups...
 "add a new module that derives from "Ninject.GlobalKernelRegistrationModule" and load it into the kernel. This will be fixed for the final release though."

i.e. something like...

```
public class MyModule : Ninject.GlobalKernelRegistrationModule<WcfRequestScopeCleanup>
{
}

//And where you load your modules...
kernel.Load<MyModule>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Ninject 3.0.0-rc2 available from Nuget. InRequestScope works for both Web and WCF requests side a side.

Comment: Thanks, I tried in an new MVC3 project, downloaded Ninject.Web.Common... Had to change OnePerRequestModule to OnePerRequestHttpModule in NinjectWebCommon class (Wrong in nuget template?) Anyway, now I get "Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Comment: Looks like its a conflict between Webactivator and Ninject.. both work fine standalone but together i get above error

Comment: The package works perfectly for me using the latest web activator. This must be a conflict with some other package/library.

Comment: I've tried it on several different machines, in a isolated test project, latest nuget manager, etc.. The strange thing is that you mention on Github that you have fixed the problems with the nuget template that i mentioned above, but the one I recevie have the errors, looks like nuget does not send the latest version... Our client uses XP and I guess you have win7 could be a problem on legacy systems, will try with my win7 x64 setup when I get home tonight..

Comment: Gets a total different error on my Dev machine at home, "Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'." On line bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel). Clean MVC3 project (Default MVC project template), Download Ninject Web extension using latest Nuget and command "Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -Pre". Only thing i change in the code is the stuff in NinjectWebCommon.cs to get it to build (Using statement and name of httpmodule), do not add bindings or anything.. Tried both with default 1.4.4 and 1.5 of Webactivator

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install the prerelease of the mvc extensions. This is actually the only one you have to get all the others are installed automatically with it. Regarding the template it is fixed on github but I didn't upload another rc just because of that since nuget wont allow me to replace one.

Comment: Install-Package Ninject.Web.Common -Pre should get the prerelease right? ah, sorry Web.Common is a generic project? Not the extension? That explains alot... :D

Comment: Use Install-Package Ninject.MVC3 -pre

Comment: Install-Package Ninject.MVC3 -PRE in fresh project (I have about 20 new MVC3 solutions on my disk now :D) gives me the same old error Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. :/

Comment: I get the same error on the test server - local machine works fine.

Comment: FYI - went back to v2 and it works as expected (not a webactivator issue).